# how to show an error message beside field in html using javascript please help me

Tags: javascript, html

i wrote a program using javascript for showing error message beside field instead of alerting but it is not working please help me to work the program

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function check()
         {
              if(document.getElementById('firstname').value==NULL || myform.firstname.value.length==0)
              {
                  document.getElementById('errorname').value="this is an invalid name";
              }
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form name="myform">
         <p>name</p>
         <input type="text" name="firstname" onblur="check()"/>
         <span id="errorname"></span>
         <br/><input type="button" value="submit" />
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is null and not NULL

Answer (score 4):

you have not given the id to you textbox also pass the value of textbox into the function

like this

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" onblur="check(this.value)"/>
```

And **JS Function**

```
function check(value)
{
     if(value.trim()=="")
     {
        document.getElementById('errorname').innerHTML="this is an invalid name";  
     }    
}
```

**[SEE FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/89dbo34z/3/)**

Comment: sorry it is not showing any message beside textbox

Comment: have you try fiddle demo?

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<form id="form">
    <p>name</p>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" /> <span id="errorname"></span>

    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var form = document.getElementById('form'),
    firstName = document.getElementById('firstname'),
    errorMessage = document.getElementById('errorname');

function check(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (firstName.value === '' || !firstName.value.length) {
        console.log('here')
        errorMessage.innerText = 'This is an invalid name';
    } else {
        errorMessage.innerText = '';
    }
}

form.addEventListener('submit', check);
```

JSFiddle example:

**http://jsfiddle.net/2etd93jL/2/**

Answer (score 1):

You are not provided ID for your input field. Add an ID and access your input field.

```
function check(){
  if(document.getElementById('firstname').value==""){
    document.getElementById('errorname').innerHTML ="this is an invalid name";
  }
}
```

And change your html field like this.

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" onblur="check()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used `document.getElementById('firstname')` but your input `input type="text" name="firstname"` doesn't have an id, only a name.  try adding `id="firstname"` to the input box.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple errors in your code listing down below:

1. Use of NULL: it is null and not NULL.
2. No id assigned as firstname and checking for that in the if loop
3. to give value to span need to use innerHTML

So your HTML code:

```
<form name="myform">  
<p>name</p><input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" onblur="check()"/><span id="errorname">    </span>
<br/><input type="button" value="submit" />
</form>
```

JS Code:

```
function check()
{
if(document.getElementById('firstname').value==null || myform.firstname.value.length==0)
{
document.getElementById('errorname').innerHTML="this is an invalid name";
}
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/19rtpbrs/)

Answer (score 0):

This is almost your code, few changes did to meet the requirement. 
Checkout the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sameerast/qfw49hmy/)

```
function check(){
     if(document.getElementById('firstname').value=='' || !document.getElementById('firstname').value.length){
          document.getElementById('errorname').innerHTML="this is an invalid name";
      }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function check() {
            if (document.myform.firstname.value === null || myform.firstname.value.length == 0) {
                document.getElementById('errorname').innerHTML = "this is an invalid name";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="myform">
        <p>name</p>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" onblur="check()" /><span id="errorname">    </span>
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```